# How to block or blacklist a particular repository or URL in maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I am trying to build a project from maven from repo_B but the project is downloading artifacts from repo_A, even though the repo_A is neither mentioned in pom.xml or settings.xml, this is very weird. It seems like it is a default for the system.

Have tried to delete .m2 and uninstall and reinstall maven. No use, it is still pulling from repo_A.

Is there a way to tell maven to blacklist a particular repository and URL and not to pull data from it.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven remote repositories can be defined in your `settings.xml` file, but also can be defined in project `pom.xml`.

So in your case additional repositories probably are defined in some of transitive dependencies.

Each remote repository has `id` and `url`.

There is not way to block remote repository by `url`, but you can do it by repository `id`.

In order to block repository you can define a `mirror` in your `settings.xml`

Block specific repositories by `id`:

```xml
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>block-repository</id>
        <blocked>true</blocked>
        <url>http://0.0.0.0</url>
        <mirrorOf>id-to-block1,id-to-block2</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

You can also block everything beyond the known ones:

```xml
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>block-repository</id>
        <blocked>true</blocked>
        <url>http://0.0.0.0</url>
        <mirrorOf>!central,!my-repo</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Blocking mirrors are introduced in `Maven 3.8.1`, so you must use this version of `Maven` at least.

You can discover `id` of repository by looking at lines in build output like:

```
Downloading from central: ...
Downloading from other-id: ...
```

References: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html